# How to use Deno for configuration of Rust app

Tags: rust, deno

I'm writing a nvim-like text editor in Rust and would like to integrate `deno_core` so that I can run user scripts that can modify some configuration options for the editor.

I would like to expose some kind of global object (akin to `vim.opts` in Neovim's lua configuration files) so that users can easily change options. I'm just not sure how I can create such an object with deno and then read the object from the Rust side.